# React JS, total score of points

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

I am new to React js. Right now I am coding an application where user can update points for each team member in a team. Increment and decrement is working very well, I got alot of help here. Right now I am trying to show the total of the points per team. Like the example below, I want the total to update when the points are changed. So if Martin gets a point, total should change to 6. And when Matthew makes a mistake, he loses a point. So then the total should decrease back to 5. But I cant figure out how to do this. Can someone help me ?

---

### Example:

John 0
Matthew 3
Martin 0
Chris 2
Anna 0
Total: 5

---

## My Code:

#### Counter Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default class Counter extends Component {
    render() {
        const { onIncrement, onDecrement } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <span>{this.formatCount()}</span>
                <button onClick={() => onIncrement(this.props.counter)}>
                    Add
                </button>

                <button
                    onClick={() => onDecrement(this.props.counter)}
                    disabled={this.props.counter.value === 0 ? "disabled" : ""}
                >
                    Delete
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    formatCount() {
        const { value } = this.props.counter;
        return value;
    }
}

if (document.getElementById("counter")) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById("counter"));
}
```

#### Counters component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Counter from "./counter";

class Counters extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            counters: [
                { id: 1, value: 0 },
                { id: 2, value: 0 },
                { id: 3, value: 0 },
                { id: 4, value: 0 },
                { id: 5, value: 0 }
            ]
        };
    }
    handleIncrement(counter) {
        const counters = [...this.state.counters];
        const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
        counters[index] = { ...counter };
        counters[index].value++;
        this.setState({ counters });
    }

    handleDecrement(counter) {
        const counters = [...this.state.counters];
        const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
        counters[index] = { ...counter };
        counters[index].value--;
        this.setState({ counters });
    }

    handleReset() {
        const counters = this.state.counters.map(c => {
            c.value = 0;
            return c;
        });
        this.setState({ counters });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleReset.bind(this)}>Reset</button>
                {this.state.counters.map(counter => (
                    <Counter
                        key={counter.id}
                        onIncrement={this.handleIncrement.bind(this)}
                        onDecrement={this.handleDecrement.bind(this)}
                        counter={counter}
                    />
                ))}

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Counters;

if (document.getElementById("counters")) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Counters />, document.getElementById("counters"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a line for the totals by adding another property to your state along with counters called `total`. This total value will need to be changed on calls to increment, decrement and reset.

Below is a demonstration of how this is accomplished:

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { onIncrement, onDecrement } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <span>{this.formatCount()}</span>
                <button onClick={() => onIncrement(this.props.counter)}>
                    Add
                </button>

                <button
                    onClick={() => onDecrement(this.props.counter)}
                    disabled={this.props.counter.value === 0 ? "disabled" : ""}
                >
                    Delete
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    formatCount() {
        const { value } = this.props.counter;
        return value;
    }
}


class Counters extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            counters: [
                { id: 1, value: 0 },
                { id: 2, value: 0 },
                { id: 3, value: 0 },
                { id: 4, value: 0 },
                { id: 5, value: 0 }
            ],
            total: 0
        };
    }
    handleIncrement(counter) {
        const total = this.state.total + 1;
        const counters = [...this.state.counters];
        const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
        counters[index] = { ...counter };
        counters[index].value++;
        this.setState({ counters: counters, total: total });
    }

    handleDecrement(counter) {
        const total = this.state.total - 1;
        const counters = [...this.state.counters];
        const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
        counters[index] = { ...counter };
        counters[index].value--;
        this.setState({ counters: counters, total: total });
    }

    handleReset() {
        const total = 0;
        const counters = this.state.counters.map(c => {
            c.value = 0;
            return c;
        });
        this.setState({ counters: counters, total: total });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleReset.bind(this)}>Reset</button>
                {this.state.counters.map(counter => (
                    <Counter
                        key={counter.id}
                        onIncrement={this.handleIncrement.bind(this)}
                        onDecrement={this.handleDecrement.bind(this)}
                        counter={counter}
                    />
                ))}
                <div>Total: {this.state.total}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Counters/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively you can skip storing the `total` value in state and dynamically find the total value based on the `counters` values like so:

```
<div>Total: {this.state.counters.map((counter) => { return counter.value; }).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. Calculate total in render: `const total = this.state.counters.reduce((sum, counter) => sum + counter.value, 0)` (see [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce))
2. Increment/decrement total with counters: `this.setState(oldState => ({total: oldState.total + 1}))`

As a good habbit you should not use `this.state` to get a value for `setState` because there can be multiple increment/decrement events. Use this syntax instead: `setState(oldState => {/* some code */; return newState})`.

Also it is better to pass `{...counter}` instead of `counter={counter}` and use `id` to [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) counter inside `handleIncrement/handleDecrement`. It is easier to track changes to props and avoid unnecessary renders this way. And there will be no problems with multiple simultaneous events on the same counter.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!